# What's the purpose for this regexp pattern?

Tags: regex

I saw the below expression in some GitHub repositories:

```
(?:(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z]|\\d|[!#\\$%&'\\*\\+\\-\\/=\\?\\^_`{\\|}~]|[\\x{00A0}-\\x{D7FF}\\x{F900}-\\x{FDCF}\\x{FDF0}-\\x{FFEF}])+(?:\\.([a-zA-Z]|\\d|[!#\\$%&'\\*\\+\\-\\/=\\?\\^_`{\\|}~]|[\\x{00A0}-\\x{D7FF}\\x{F900}-\\x{FDCF}\\x{FDF0}-\\x{FFEF}])+)*)|(?:(?:\\x22)(?:(?:(?:(?:\\x20|\\x09)*(?:\\x0d\\x0a))?(?:\\x20|\\x09)+)?(?:(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x1f\\x7f]|\\x21|[\\x23-\\x5b]|[\\x5d-\\x7e]|[\\x{00A0}-\\x{D7FF}\\x{F900}-\\x{FDCF}\\x{FDF0}-\\x{FFEF}])|(?:(?:[\\x01-\\x09\\x0b\\x0c\\x0d-\\x7f]|[\\x{00A0}-\\x{D7FF}\\x{F900}-\\x{FDCF}\\x{FDF0}-\\x{FFEF}]))))*(?:(?:(?:\\x20|\\x09)*(?:\\x0d\\x0a))?(\\x20|\\x09)+)?(?:\\x22))))@(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z]|\\d|[\\x{00A0}-\\x{D7FF}\\x{F900}-\\x{FDCF}\\x{FDF0}-\\x{FFEF}])|(?:(?:[a-zA-Z]|\\d|[\\x{00A0}-\\x{D7FF}\\x{F900}-\\x{FDCF}\\x{FDF0}-\\x{FFEF}])(?:[a-zA-Z]|\\d|-|\\.|~|[\\x{00A0}-\\x{D7FF}\\x{F900}-\\x{FDCF}\\x{FDF0}-\\x{FFEF}])*(?:[a-zA-Z]|\\d|[\\x{00A0}-\\x{D7FF}\\x{F900}-\\x{FDCF}\\x{FDF0}-\\x{FFEF}])))\\.)+(?:(?:[a-zA-Z]|[\\x{00A0}-\\x{D7FF}\\x{F900}-\\x{FDCF}\\x{FDF0}-\\x{FFEF}])|(?:(?:[a-zA-Z]|[\\x{00A0}-\\x{D7FF}\\x{F900}-\\x{FDCF}\\x{FDF0}-\\x{FFEF}])(?:[a-zA-Z]|\\d|-|\\.|~|[\\x{00A0}-\\x{D7FF}\\x{F900}-\\x{FDCF}\\x{FDF0}-\\x{FFEF}])*(?:[a-zA-Z]|[\\x{00A0}-\\x{D7FF}\\x{F900}-\\x{FDCF}\\x{FDF0}-\\x{FFEF}])))\\.?$
```

e.g.: https://github.com/go-playground/validator/blob/059510c3bff4688135f150f0ed6e87d18539ca94/regexes.go#L18

But I don't understand why it includes `[\\x{00A0}-\\x{D7FF}\\x{F900}-\\x{FDCF}\\x{FDF0}-\\x{FFEF}]`.

What's the purpose of this ?

Comment: those are range of character. Just like you would do `[a-z]`. Those just happen to be in hexadecimal. It probably has something to do with special character that cannot be represent in character like the one i'm writing right now.

Comment: Thanks. It's the range of multibyte characters !

Comment: Tip: When trying to analyse a "complex" regex, first remove "unnecessary" constructs, such as non-capturing group (?: ) and "unnecessary" escaped characters. Although the regex may not run it will be easier to understand.